# Criar link para download de arquivo encriptografado em PHP

Tags: php, sql, download

Tenho um site em que os usuarios podem fazer o download dos arquivos.

Esses arquivos estão com o caminho em uma tabela sql e tem uma chave de acesso e o id do pedido.

Hj o download do arquivo é direto na url, ex:

```
<a href="/downloads/arquivo.mp3" download>Download</a>
```

Eu queria algo que fizesse o download sem mostrar o link do arquivo, que ele fizesse alguma coisa como: site.com/?usuario=123&pedido=18&chave=28 daí quando ele acessar esse link, ele fizesse o download do arquivo, pegando as infos da tabela "downloads"

Na tabela downloads eu tenho

```
id|pedido|chave|arquivo
1 |  18  | 28  |downloads/arquivo.mp3
```

A parte de fazer a verificação na tabela, fazendo a consulta e trazendo as informações sei fazer, vou usar o $_GET e usar a consulta SQL, mas não sei como fazer ele fazer o download no clique de download sem mostrar o caminho

Comment: $_POST não resolve em vez de $_GET?

Comment: Show isso mesmo que precisava!  não tinha achado.